# python-docx: add picture from the web

Tags: python, django, docx, python-docx

I am using python-docx with django to generate word documents.

Is there a way to use `add_picture` to add an image from the web rather then from the file system?

In word, when I select to add a picture, I can just give the URL.
I tried to simply so the same and write:

```
document.add_picture("http://icdn4.digitaltrends.com/image/microsoft_xp_bliss_desktop_image-650x0.jpg")
```

and got error:

> IOError: [Errno 22] invalid mode ('rb') or filename:
>   'http://icdn4.digitaltrends.com/image/microsoft_xp_bliss_desktop_image-650x0.jpg'

Comment: If `add_picture` can accept a file object, then yes. Otherwise, no.

Comment: add_picture for file works fine. From docx documentation: "Add the image identified by image_descriptor to the document at its native size..."

Comment: What type can `image_descriptor` be?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not very elegant, but i found a solution, based on the question in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22505922/python-elementtree-xml-ioerror-errno-22-invalid-mode-rb-or-filename)

my code now looks like that:

```
import urllib2, StringIO
image_from_url = urllib2.urlopen(url_value)
io_url = StringIO.StringIO()
io_url.write(image_from_url.read())
io_url.seek(0)
try:
  document.add_picture(io_url ,width=Px(150))
```

and this works fine.

Comment: Why not pass `image_from_url` directly to `add_picture`?

Comment: i tried, but then i get: "AttributeError: addinfourl instance has no attribute 'seek'"

Comment: In that case you solution might be the most straightforward.

Answer (score 1):

If you use `docxtemplater` (command line interface),

you can create your own templates and embed images with a URL.

See : https://github.com/edi9999/docxtemplater

[docxtemplater command line interface](http://docxtemplater.readthedocs.org/en/latest/cli.html)

[docxtemplater image replacing](http://docxtemplater.readthedocs.org/en/latest/configuration.html#image-replacing)

Comment: i took a brief look at the templater and from what i see this does not answer my need, as i have to embed the picture(s) at run time based on the data from the client. also the number of images may change from one run to the other.

Comment: Docxtemplater will fetch the images at runtime, you can even use a URL to identify the image. For the mutliple images, you can use loops for this: http://javascript-ninja.fr/docxgenjs/examples/demo.html#qrcodeloop

Comment: Thanks. for now - ill stick with my server side solution that i described above.

Answer (score 1):

Below is a fresh implementation for Python 3:

```
from io import BytesIO

import requests
from docx import Document
from docx.shared import Inches

response = requests.get(your_image_url)  # no need to add stream=True
# Access the response body as bytes
#   then convert it to in-memory binary stream using `BytesIO`     
binary_img = BytesIO(response.content)  

document = Document()
# `add_picture` supports image path or stream, we use stream
document.add_picture(binary_img, width=Inches(2))
document.save('demo.docx')
```